# Why does my email received not have any content?

Tags: php, html

I have a form that captures and forwards a user's name, email, and a comment.

I receive the email in my inbox but the values are blank.

Example of the email received:

```
Name:
Email:
Comment:
```

Here is the code on my index.php file

```
<?php 
 $name="";
 $from="";
 $message="";
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $from=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
  $message=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
  $to="email@exampel.com";
  include("library/send_email.php");
 }
?>

<form id="contactform" name="contactform" action="" method="post">
 <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" required>
 <input type="text"  id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="<?php echo $from;?>" required>
 <textarea id="comments" name="comments" placeholder="Message" required><?php echo $message;?></textarea>
 <button name="submit" id="submit" class="contact-btn-submit" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

There is also a send_email.php file which includes the following:

```
<?php
 $send_email= new class_email_sender($name,$from,$to,$message);
 $send_email->send_email();
?>
```

Why do the emails not include the user's name, email, or comments?

Comment: What is the content of `var_dump($_POST)` ?
And why you don't use `<input type="submit" .../>` for the submit button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
$name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$from=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$message=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']);
```

As you don't have a valid `mysql_*` connection, `mysql_real_escape_string` returns `false` so all your values are `false` which results in empty strings when you send your mail.

**Note** that you should not use this function for anything other than preparing data to be inserted in a database and even then you should switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and have been removed from php 7.

Comment: That's it. Removed the mysql_real_escape_string bits and the email now has values. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have assigned the variables(before if statement) to avoid the PHP errors, do it this way to avoid conflicts etc.

```
$name=isset($_POST['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']) : "";
$email=isset($_POST['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) : ""; 
$message=isset($_POST['comments']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comments']) : "";
```

Also note what jeroen said. Use `mysqli` instead.